# Let's get critical: Jun 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-evaluation

We all love [Ebooks Stack Exchange](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Is it possible to make a Kindle ebook look exactly like my InDesign / PDF file?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/5907/is-it-possible-to-make-a-kindle-ebook-look-exactly-like-my-indesign-pdf-file)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to prevent Calibre replacing my cover image](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/5881/how-to-prevent-calibre-replacing-my-cover-image)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Could you advise an Open Source method for creating an online library?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/5882/could-you-advise-an-open-source-method-for-creating-an-online-library)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the different compatible formats between Kindle Paperwhite and Kindle Fire?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/what-is-the-different-compatible-formats-between-kindle-paperwhite-and-kindle-fi)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [SVG covers: which size must be used?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/5935/svg-covers-which-size-must-be-used)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Screen Rendering only 2/3 of eBook - Troubleshooting Ideas?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/5918/screen-rendering-only-2-3-of-ebook-troubleshooting-ideas)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [google ebooks from linux to ereader](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/5905/google-ebooks-from-linux-to-ereader)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [No .indd files to convert for Kindle publishing](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/5892/no-indd-files-to-convert-for-kindle-publishing)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the native pixel resolution of the viewable area on a Kindle Paperwhite 2 when displaying a .pdf file?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/5901/what-is-the-native-pixel-resolution-of-the-viewable-area-on-a-kindle-paperwhite)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Kindle - single gesture / action to go "back"](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/5903/kindle-single-gesture-action-to-go-back)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---